# Perform ajax call with Action in MVC5

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, devexpress

I know this is a common question that was answered a lot of times for similar requeriments, but I don't find the way to fix it in my Scenario.

I am using DevExpress MVC components. There is a treeview like the following:

```
@Html.DevExpress().TreeView(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "NavigationClientsList";
    settings.AllowSelectNode = true;
    Model.ForEach(_client =>
    {
        settings.Nodes.Add(node =>
        {
            node.Name = String.Format("{0}_client_{1}", settings.Name, _client.ClientID);
            node.Text = _client.ClientName;
        });
    });

    settings.ClientSideEvents.NodeClick = "OnTreeViewNodeClick";

    settings.PreRender = (source, e) =>
    {
        ASPxTreeView treeView = (ASPxTreeView)source;
        treeView.ExpandAll();
    };
}).GetHtml()
```

And my NodeClick Event:

```
function OnTreeViewNodeClick(s, e) {
    if (e.node.name.indexOf("_client_") > -1) {
        var tmpDivDescription = e.node.name.split("_");
        if (tmpDivDescription.length = 3) {
            var tmpID = tmpDivDescription[2];
            //alert(tmpID);
            //$("#testDisplay").text("ALGO");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Home/Client/',//'@Url.Action("Client", "Home")',//'Home/Client/25',//'@Url.Action("Client", "Home")',
                data: { 'id': tmpID },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (result) {
                    //alert('OK!')
                    $("#DataDisplay").html(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr) { alert('ERROR!' + xhr.responseText) }
            });
        }

    } else {

    }
}
```

I tried several two ways to perform the Ajax call

`url: 'Home/Client/'` and `url: '@Url.Action("Client", "Home")'`

The first works as expected, but when trying to use the second with UrlAction the Server complains the resource could not be found:

Beschreibung: HTTP 404. Die gesuchte Ressource oder eine ihrer Abhängigkeiten wurde möglicherweise entfernt, umbenannt oder ist vorübergehend nicht verfügbar. Überprüfen Sie folgende URL, und stellen Sie sicher, dass sie richtig geschrieben wurde.

Angeforderter URL: /@Url.Action("Client", "Home")

As you can see, the requested URL adds an "/". I don't know if this is the reason of my problems.

For all Topics and resources I have found, they use the "normal" Url.Action Format.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using areas?

Comment: I have this `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` within the Application_Start method but I didn't define anything Special. I keep the Default RegisterRoutes from the template.

Comment: is your NodeClick event in an external file? If so razor syntax will not be available

Comment: Yes, my OnTreeViewNodeClick is inside a separate js file I link from the view. Should be the JavaScript function in the cshtml view?

Comment: If you are using areas, you may need to specify the area name - e.g. `'@Url.Action("Client", "Home", new { area = "" })'` or `'@Url.Action("Client", "Home", new { area = "yourArea" })'`

Comment: Razor code is not parsed on external js files, so that code needs to be in your view, or you need to define a variable in the view so it can be access in the external file - `var url = '@Url.Action("Client", "Home")';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Razor syntax in external js files. Instead you'll have to use either...

1. The static solution that you tried, `'/Home/Client/'`
2. Move the entire JavaScript to your view (not recommended)
3. Use a JavaScript variable to store the URL and pass it to the external file:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var myPath = '@Url.Action("Client","Home")';
   </script>
   ```

   And in external JavaScript file:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url: myPath;
       ....
   ```
4. Another similar option is to use a html5 data-attribute. Usually the option I choose if the ajax call is placed in an event, like `click`:

   ```
   <span data-url='@Url.Action("Client","Home")'>...</span>
   ```

   And the external JavaScript file:

   ```
   $("span").click(function() {
       $.ajax({
           url: $(this).attr("data-url"), //or $(this).data("url")
           ....
   ```

Comment: @Mackan Which method is better to use then, 1 or 3?

Comment: @frost It depends on your project and preference. For maintainability, scalability and sharing code with others, using a view for all js variables with paths seems like the best idea. But if it's a smaller project, and it suits your preference, using static url's directly in the js file works fine. Personally I've used both, and a couple of other methods (like setting the url in a data-attribute etc.).